# How to debug variables in Autohotkey without using MsgBox?

Tags: debugging, autohotkey

When debugging scripts, you often need to know the value of your variables to know exactly what is going on. Outputting variables with [MsgBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm) to tackle this problem is annoying and inefficient.

Is there a function that can help me with debugging variables?

I want it to write down all my local variables, their names and corresponding values as well as the name of the current procedure being executed to an ini file. Are there debugging tools that can provide this functionality, possibly in real time?

The name of the procedure may be challenging to do, but is there a way that at least all the local variables can get enumerated and written away?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [ListVars command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ListVars.htm). It lists all of the variables.

You can also get more extensive information using a method like this:

```
MsgBox, % GetAhkStats("lines")
MsgBox, % GetAhkStats("variables")
MsgBox, % GetAhkStats("hotkeys")
Stat1 := GetAhkStats("history")
MsgBox, %Stat1%
Return

a::a
b::b
c::c
d::d

GetAhkStats(xxSection="", xxUseWindow=99, xxDestroyAfter=1)
{
  xxSectionN = Lines|Variables|Hotkeys|History
  If xxSection=
    xxSection = History
  Loop, Parse, xxSectionN, |
    IfInString, A_LoopField, %xxSection% 
      xxSection = %A_Index%
  DetectHiddenWindows, On
  SetTitleMatchMode, 2
  Gui, %xxUseWindow%:Show, Hide
  xxHidWin := WinExist(A_ScriptFullPath " - AutoHotkey v")
  xxOldpar := DllCall("GetParent", "UInt", xxHidWin)
  DllCall("SetParent", "UInt", xxHidWin, "UInt", (GuiGetHWND("", xxUseWindow)))
  WinMenuSelectItem, ahk_id %xxHidWin%,, View, %xxSection%&
  Loop {
    Sleep, 50
    ControlGetText, xxOut1, Edit1, ahk_id %xxHidWin%
    If xxOut1<>
      break
  }
  WinHide, ahk_id %xxHidWin%
  DllCall("SetParent", "UInt", xxHidWin, "UInt", xxOldpar)
  If (xxDestroyAfter)
    Gui, %xxUseWindow%:Destroy
Return, xxOut1
}

GuiGetHWND(xxClassNN="", xxGUI=1)
{
  If (xxGUI)
    Gui, %xxGUI%:+LastFound
  xxGui_hwnd := WinExist()
  If xxClassNN=
    Return, xxGui_hwnd
  ControlGet, xxOutputVar, Hwnd,, %xxClassNN%, ahk_id %xxGui_hwnd%
Return, xxOutputVar
}
```

[Source](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/9267-getting-the-scan-code/#entry58844)

Comment: @Khalil I think folks just misread your answer. I removed the comments on the answer you posted since they didn't really make a lot of sense. You might want to check out the [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) page for some tips on writing comprehensive and clear answers to make sure this kind of confusion doesn't arise again.

Answer (score -7):

listvars does the trick for me.

Comment: If you've solved the problem yourself, it does help to explain, rather than it "doing the trick" for you, how you used it and to explicitly note that you resolved your own question, otherwise you leave it open to interpretation by others.

Comment: As a follow-up, you were looking for "all my local variables, their names and corresponding values as well as the name of the current procedure being executed to". This answer could be enhanced by providing the exact command for ListVars (I'm sure you needed to set specific flags to get what you wanted) to perform this very task you've requested.

Comment: @JoshDM That would have been a good addition. Except that the documentation doesn't provide that info. Where did you read about that?

Comment: I'm just making assumptions since listvars appears to be a script; most scripts allow for options to be set.